# Using oracle plsql procedure how can get more than one rows or all rows in table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am using plsql procedure    in oracle . I need to retrieve  more than one rows. My partial code..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure PC_APP.Test_proc1( ) is
BEGIN

    SELECT * from table;

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use  [Ref Cursors](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Oracle/Working-with-REF-CURSOR-in-PL-SQL/) to allow recordsets to be returned from stored procedures and functions .

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE  PC_APP.Test_proc1 (prc out sys_refcursor)
 IS
 BEGIN

 OPEN prc  SELECT * from mytable;

 END;
```

On command line

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> execute prc(:rc)
SQL> print rc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  PC_APP.Test_proc1 (prc out sys_refcursor)
 IS
 BEGIN

 OPEN prc  for  SELECT * from mytable;

 END;
```